# list file and using awk to get comment

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, awk

I want to get the all comment of all files in a folder.

And what I have tried is

`ls -R | awk '/<!--/,/-->/' >> result`

But it shows nothing in the result file.

But if I use the `awk '/<!--/,/-->/' >> result` to a file it works.

The html comment tag is `<!-- some text here -->`.

How should I fix it.

Comment: The issue you are having is that `ls -R` creates a list of file names, and most likely, none of them have a name that will match your comment delimiter patterns (if they do, you've likely encountered certain ... complications ... with such file names; or you will later). You want to search the *content* of the files, not the names of the files. Something along the lines of `find . -type f -name "*.html" -print0 | xargs -0 awk '....'`. But an HTML parser might be a better idea than `awk`...

Comment: @twalberg you are right and the method you give woks. What I want to ask is that why I do `awk '/<!--/,/-->/'  filename >> result`, it works. But when I using the stdout by the `ls` it fails, aren't they all string?

Comment: @twalberg If you could, post it to the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that `ls -R` creates a list of file names that you are searching for your pattern. Most likely, none of the files have a name that will match your comment delimiter patterns (if they do, you've likely encountered certain ... complications ... with such file names; or you will later).

You want to search the *content* of the files, not the names of the files. Something along the lines of:

```
find . -type f -name "*.html" -print0 | xargs -0 awk '....'
```

But an HTML parser might be a better idea than `awk`, for parsing HTML.